# Значение цифры в скобках в записи type=INT(11)

Tags: mysql

Что значит, когда в БД (MySQL) пишется type=INT(11), что в скобочках?

Comment: Короч проблема втом, что число кот нач с нуля) полностью не передается, например
0508245782
в БД это будет
508245782
Как избежать этого?

Comment: Зачем вам ведущие нули?

Comment: что-бы логин был номером телефона

Comment: Используйте varchar(12), например

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Если это знаковый INT(11), то:
11 - это ограничение числа символов вывода - знак числа и 10 цифр.
Реально для данных - 32 бита, один ( первый - наверное всегда ) из которых на знак числа.

Answer (score 1):

Сорри, ошибся. Вот [здесь](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/numeric-types.html) все написано.

> *For example, for a column declared as INT(4) ZEROFILL, a value of 5 is
> retrieved as 0005.*

Т.е. по идее можно и `INT` использовать с параметром `ZEROFILL`. Здесь 4 - число разрядов.

Answer (score -2):

Это число байт, которыми записывается указанное число. К примеру, 11 байт = 8<sup>11</sup> =8589934592 различных чисел (unsigned int).

Comment: Переделать в  string.

Comment: Вы неправы. 11 - это ширина поля для отображения. А `INT` в MySQL всегда 4 байта.